# Go through two different arrays inside foreach

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, foreach

I have two different arrays which have the **same length**.

```
myData = [["site_1", 3722, 2938, 2529, 3419, 3495, 3477],
          ["site_2", 115, 55, 56, 111, 113, 124],
          ["site_3", 13, 11, 10, 17, 17, 16],
          ["site_4", 16, 11, 10, 17, 17, 16],
          ["site_5", 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
         ];

booleanData = [true, false, false, true, true];
```

I'm already using the first array to compute some data and I want to use the second one to add that information for each of the elements of the array.

```
_.chain(myCtrl.chartData.myData).forEach(data => {
myCtrl.legendData.push({
    siteName: data[0],
    color: myCtrl.chartData.chart.color(data[0])
});
}).value();
```

The above code works fine, it goes through the array and gets the string from each sub-array and computes a color for it.

I want to add the `booleanData` and I tried it like this:

```
_.chain(myCtrl.chartData.myData).forEach(data => {
myCtrl.legendData.push({
    siteName: data[0],
    color: myCtrl.chartData.chart.color(data[0]),
    hasIt: myCtrl.chartData.booleanData[data]
});
}).value();
```

I understand that the parameter should not be `[data]` but I don't know how to do it to work fine.

**The result I want in this case is that `legendData` to be:**

```
[ {siteName: "name_1", color: "#4ae412", hasIt: true},
  {siteName: "name_2", color: "#4ae412", hasIt: false},
  {siteName: "name_3", color: "#4ae412", hasIt: false},
  {siteName: "name_4", color: "#4ae412", hasIt: true},
  {siteName: "name_5", color: "#4ae412", hasIt: true}
]
```

Color has no effect on this, you can ignore it.

Do you have any idea?

Comment: please add the wanted result as well.

Comment: @NinaScholz I want that the forEach to go for same element for `booleanData` as it goes for `myData`. to create a pair of values between them, they have same length

Comment: @rareșmigea: please show the code result you want to receive, rather than explaining it with words; it's much easier that way :)

Comment: @DavidThomas I edited it now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using forEach and keeping strictly as you have and asked, you can get your results as such:

```
var myData = [["site_1", 3722, 2938, 2529, 3419, 3495, 3477],
          ["site_2", 115, 55, 56, 111, 113, 124],
          ["site_3", 13, 11, 10, 17, 17, 16],
          ["site_4", 16, 11, 10, 17, 17, 16],
          ["site_5", 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
         ];

var booleanData = [true, false, false, true, true], legendData = [];

myData.forEach(function(x, i){
    legendData.push({sitename: myData[i][0], color: '#4ae412', hasIt: booleanData[i]});
});

console.log(legendData); // [{color: "#4ae412", hasIt: true, sitename: "site_1"}, {color: "#4ae412", hasIt: false, sitename: "site_2"}, {color: "#4ae412", hasIt: false, sitename: "site_2"}, {color: "#4ae412", hasIt: true, sitename: "site_4"}, {color: "#4ae412", hasIt: true, sitename: "site_5"}]
```

This has your color hardcoded as I am unaware of how you are figuring out the color. But you can simply do that calculation and store it as a variable and replace the hardcoded color with said variable.

Answer (score 2):

Try the following usage of forEach, the callback can acept `item` and `index` as the second argument.

```
var myData = [["site_1", 3722, 2938, 2529, 3419, 3495, 3477],
          ["site_2", 115, 55, 56, 111, 113, 124],
          ["site_3", 13, 11, 10, 17, 17, 16],
          ["site_4", 16, 11, 10, 17, 17, 16],
          ["site_5", 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
         ];

var booleanData = [true, false, false, true, true];

var result = {};
myData.forEach((item, index) => {
    let name = item[0]
    result[name] = booleanData[index]
})
console.log(result)
// {site_1: true, site_2: false, site_3: false, site_4: true, site_5: true}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could map the wanted properties for a new object and get anarray of objects.

```js
var myData = [["site_1", 3722, 2938, 2529, 3419, 3495, 3477], ["site_2", 115, 55, 56, 111, 113, 124], ["site_3", 13, 11, 10, 17, 17, 16], ["site_4", 16, 11, 10, 17, 17, 16], ["site_5", 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]],
    booleanData = [true, false, false, true, true],
    result = myData.map(([siteName], i) => ({ siteName, color: "#4ae412", hasIt: booleanData[i] }));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it seems correct but in my case it wouldn't fit because I cannot change too much in my code, it could affect other functionalities